# push spark dataframes(each row as a individual message) to kafka using python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have my pyspark code which basically gets a data dump from cassandra db. Afterfew manipulations i am right now pushing dataframes row by row using for loop over the dataframes. Since this is time consuming operation. Is it possible to push the complete dataframe to kafka.
I have tried pushing the whole data but the dataframe gets pushed inside as a list of rows(single message inside kafka). I want to have each row as a individual message in kafka.

Comment: The common pattern would be to ingest from a source datastore using Kafka Connect, but I don't see a source for Cassandra in the [available list](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/). Is Cassandra the original source of the data; do you have the option of getting it into Kafka more directly (and then perhaps streaming it into Cassandra as needed using the Kafka Connect Cassandra sink that does exist?)

Comment: No, Cassandra is the original source and i need to take a data dump from cassandra and perform few transformations and then push those to kafka. I am using a cassandra connector org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra to fetch the data from cassandra and then pushing the data to kafka using kafkaProducer.